# HiveContext: Can't able to view temp table via JDBC client

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

> In pyspark,

registered a temp table

```
from pyspark import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from test").collect()
df.registerTempTable("testing")
sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()
+--------------------+-----------+
|           tableName|isTemporary|
+--------------------+-----------+
|             testing|       true|
|               check|      false|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

I can able to view the temp table "testing" from pyspark

I started spark thrift server

Started JDBC client and connected to spark thrift server,

```
$ ./bin/beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://ip:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://ip:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://ip: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://ip:10000:
16/03/06 13:17:41 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: :10000
16/03/06 13:17:41 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: :10000
16/03/06 13:17:41 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://ip:10000
Connected to: Spark SQL (version 1.5.2)
Driver: Spark Project Core (version 1.5.2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://ip.> show tables;
+-------------+--------------+--+
|  tableName  | isTemporary  |
+-------------+--------------+--+
| check       | false        |
+-------------+--------------+--+
2 rows selected (0.842 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://ip.>
```

I can't able to view the temp table.
Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Temp table will only survive in your current session. That means your new session via beeline cannot see temporary table `testing`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that.
 After registering the temp table, I started a thrift server programmatically pointing to that particular HiveContext. Then it worked fine